# Subtraction of float64 decimals doesn't appear to be working in Go?

Tags: go

I have some code that requires high precision and I'm trying to troubleshoot a bug that I believe is occurring due to rounding errors during a string of calculations. While debugging, I encountered some weird behavior when attempting to subtract a small float64 from another float64.

```
offset := width1 - 1.0
offsetY := rods[0].short_axis[1] * offset
y := rods[0].rotated_vertices[7]
y_adjusted := y - offsetY
fmt.Printf("offsetY = %.120f\n", offsetY)
fmt.Printf("original y = %.120f\n", y)
fmt.Printf("adjusted y = %.120f\n", y_adjusted)
fmt.Println()

offsetX := rods[0].short_axis[0] * offset
x := rods[0].rotated_vertices[6]
x_adjusted := x - offsetX
fmt.Printf("offsetX = %.120f\n", offsetX)
fmt.Printf("original x = %.120f\n", x)
fmt.Printf("adjusted x = %.120f\n", x_adjusted)
fmt.Println()
```

If I run the above code, I get the following output

```
offsetY = -0.000000000000000192296268638356406290991112813876676018712131416808774897475586840300820767879486083984375000000000000000
original y = 3.183012701892220519539478118531405925750732421875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
adjusted y = 3.183012701892220519539478118531405925750732421875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

offsetX = 0.000000000000000111022302462515641716411522730772571691741167456465161356149451421515550464391708374023437500000000000000
original x = 0.852885682970025094107313634594902396202087402343750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
adjusted x = 0.852885682970024983085011172079248353838920593261718750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Even though `offsetX` and `offsetY` are the same magnitude, only one of these calculations appears to be working. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Floating points are approximations: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Subtraction of floats of vastly different magnitude doesn't work in any language. Stay away from numerical code until you understand floating point arithmetic and stability of numerical algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I read the doc and i find this:
"For floating-point values, width sets the minimum width of the field and precision sets the number of places after the decimal, if appropriate, except that for %g/%G precision sets the maximum number of significant digits (trailing zeros are removed). For example, given 12.345 the format %6.3f prints 12.345 while %.3g prints 12.3. **The default precision for %e, %f and %#g is 6**; for %g it is the smallest number of digits necessary to identify the value uniquely."

So the default precision is 6.
Because it isn't a language problem but a problem with how floats are represented in general.

[Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)